# Bash - how do I wipe the contents of all files in a directory

Tags: bash, shell

is it possible to wipe the contents of all given files in a directory?  e.g. if I have a bunch of .csv files I want wiped.

I generally use "# > .csv" on the command line for a single csv file, but a "# > *.csv" results in a error: bash: *.csv: ambiguous redirect

I have tried piping /dev/null to *.csv but get same result.  When I have a directory full of files whose content I want wiped, it's a real pain.

If I use a script and for loop on all the files I get the same error when using the redirect on the $f (the file) in the loop.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for f in *.csv; do
  > "$f"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `truncate` for the same :

```
truncate -s 0 *.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say "*wipe*" you mean:

- "overwite" with random content,
- or an simple "truncate"
- or even simpler delete?

Delete:

```
rm *.csv #will delete all .csv file in the currect directory
```

Truncate

```
see @John Zwinkcs answer
```

Overwrite with random and delete

```
shopt -s nullglob
for file in *.csv
do
    echo "wiping $file" >&2
    eval "$(gstat -c 'count=%b;blocksize=%B' "$file")"
    dd if=/dev/random of="$file" bs="$blocksize" count="$count" 2>/dev/null
    rm "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a way using sed

```
sed -i '1,$d' *.csv
```

also

```
sed -ni '' *.csv
```